# Can we use ObjectiveC and Swift code together in Flutter?

Tags: swift, objective-c, flutter, dart

I have a use case, where we am using two different classes written in Swift and Objective-C. So Is it possible to user these two language together in the same project?

My current code is written on Swift, Now there is one new library (iHealthLab), which we are gonna use, is written on Objective-C. So I want to use their library code in my project.

So is it possible?
Is there any example where someone have done this before?

Comment: yes, it is possible to use both on same ios project. some ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-do-i-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon , I dont know but if I correct. this is what you want